# how to assign an element to a PHP assositive array?

Tags: php

How to assign an element to a PHP associative array?

For example, I attempt this but not working.

```
$testSCSI = array('test' => <input type="checkbox"> Test Results</input>);

echo json_encode($testSCSI);
```

When reading the json from my jquery code, it only gives me value of "Test Results" and not the checkbox.

Comment: Where are the quote characters?

Comment: Better question, how is that not a run time syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Did you forget the quotes?

```
$testSCSI = array('test' => '<input type="checkbox"> Test Results</input>');
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the invalid "close tag". See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: Rob is right, there is no closing input tag but rather a '/' at the end of the opening tag.  See my answer below.

Comment: I am not sure how this is the accepted answer when </input> is not a valid HTML end tag...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in your jQuery code, not the PHP.

The PHP should be outputting this:

```
{"test":"<input type=\"checkbox\"> Test Results</input>"}
```

And then in jQuery you want to make sure you're using `html()` rather than `text()` to assign it.

Comment: The original poster: "When reading the json from my jquery code"

Answer (score 0):

That really isn't how arrays work, you don't store HTML elements in them you store data elements.  An example associative array might look something like:

```
$a = array("test1"=>"value1", "test2"=>"value2");
```

You could accomplish what you are trying to do by using properly quoted strings for your HTML elements.  You could also use single quotes so you don't have to escape the quotes in type parameter.

```
$a = array("test"=>"<input type=\"checkbox\" />Test Results\n");
```

HTH.